# Mandatory executable task in cruisecontrol.net

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

Is there any way to run an exec task in cruise-control.net even if errors have occurred in the previous tasks. The same functionality which we get through the finally block in .net. 
I want to execute a set of tasks which is independent of the success/failure of the previous tasks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is usually achieved using the [`<publishers/>`](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Task+And+Publisher+Blocks) element, which accepts the same Tasks as the `<tasks/>` element. Publishers are always executed, even if the `<tasks/>` fail.